# Pandas - Unstack/pivot a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Column A | Column B | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | A |
| 2 | 8 | A |
| 3 | 9 | B |
| 4 | 10 | B |
| 5 | 11 | C |
| 6 | 12 | C |

I would like to write code to produce the following dataframe:

| Category A |  | Category B |  | Category C |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Column A | Column B | Column A | Column B | Column A | Column B |
| 1 | 7 | 3 | 9 | 5 | 11 |
| 2 | 8 | 4 | 10 | 6 | 12 |

I've tried pd.pivot_table, but am not able to figure it out. Can someone help me with this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy index to use pivot table with:

```
out = df.pivot_table(
    columns="Category",
    index=df.groupby("Category").cumcount()
)
```

which has output:

```
         Column A       Column B
Category        A  B  C        A   B   C
0               1  3  5        7   9  11
1               2  4  6        8  10  12
```

I don't know if there's any simple way to rearrange the columns to be in your format within `pivot_table` itself. Here is a way by doing some post processing:

```
final = out.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
```

final:

```
Category        A                 B                 C
         Column A Column B Column A Column B Column A Column B
0               1        7        3        9        5       11
1               2        8        4       10        6       12
```

Comment: get out, you beat me to it, again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you cannot identify each row uniquely to be able to apply `pivot`. To this end, create a "within-group" index as follows.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# setup sample data
data = StringIO("""
Column A;Column B;Category
1;7;A
2;8;A
3;9;B
4;10;B
5;11;C
6;12;C
"""
)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";")

# assign a within-group index
df['id'] = df.groupby('Category').cumcount()

# now apply pivot
df = df.pivot(index='id', columns='Category', values=['Column A', 'Column B'])
```

Now, you can apply `swaplevel` and `sort_index` to match the desired result

```py
df.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```